# Should there be no foot sound when jogging?

Tags: running

I heard that when jogging/running that there should be no foot thud sounds when landing. Is it true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask:

> Is it true?

Well, to an extent, yes.  But don't worry too much about achieving silence.

A thud sound whilst running generally indicates that the heel is striking the ground on the downstep more than it should.  However, rather than focus on reducing the sound or feel of the thud, you should improves the mechanics of your running and the thud will reduce as a result.

The thud is caused because the impact shock is not absorbed by the flesh of the foot arch or the muscles in the calf.  Instead, the force travels up through the bone at the front and can lead to [shin splints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin_splints) in the muscles there.

To counter this, you need to spend as much of your time running on the balls of your feet as you can.

Try rolling your foot landing rather than coming down at an angle.  You can reduce your stride to achieve this.  Watch a video of a long-distance runner to see how they run without much impact against the ground.

Comment: Here's what I like about this answer: "...rather than focus on reducing the sound or feel of the thud, you should improves the mechanics of your running and the thud will reduce as a result." Too much running advice out there focuses on symptoms without discussing underlying causes.

Comment: "You need to spend as much of your time running on the balls of your feet as you can." Mid-foot is better as staying on the balls of your feet will engage your calf muscle which will tire out over longer distances. Mid-foot strike engages the glute and quad while using the hamstring to propel forward. Staying on the ball of your foot will use the calf muscle for landing and propelling which is great for sprinting/quick steps but bad for distance.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is 'Yes'.
Moreover, I think that making no footstep sound with intention is a good way to naturally get technical skill, or to easily improve your running technic. 
Because doing that, indirectly, you will absorbe shocks with you calfs and your thighs (muscles), and not with your bones. Your bone legs will not be hurt because of the non-max outstretched stride.

Answer (score 0):

No "thud" sound?  Yes.  No sound at all?  No.

In general, the reason you don't want to hear much noise is because it means your body is going up and down and not forward. The "thud" sound means you are using excess force (energy) down against the ground when what you want is to maximize the amount of energy you are using to go forward. Since energy is a zero-sum game when running, that means you won't go as fast or as far as your potential energy allows.